# How To Enable all Inputs In a Table Row With An Edit Button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this example](http://www.bootply.com/GZulessL2c) and let me know how I can use jquery to enable all inputs existing in the same row as Clicked "Edit" button `.btn-edit` class?

js:

```
$(".btn-edit").on("click", function(){
  $(this).attr("disabled", true);   
});
```

and HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Col 1
      </th>
              <th>
        Col 2
      </th>
            <th>
        Col 4
      </th>
            <th>
        Col 4
      </th>
      <th>
        Col 5
      </th>
      <th>
        Col 3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
                <td>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" disabled="disabled">
      </td>
                          <td>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" disabled="disabled">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" disabled="disabled">
      </td>
              <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Update
                    </button>
      </td>
      <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="disabled">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                    </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-edit">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>  Edit
                    </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
                <td>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" disabled="disabled">
      </td>
                          <td>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" disabled="disabled">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" disabled="disabled">
      </td>
              <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Update
                    </button>
      </td>
      <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="disabled">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                    </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>  Edit
                    </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
                <td>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" disabled="disabled">
      </td>
                          <td>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" disabled="disabled">
      </td>
      <td>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" disabled="disabled">
      </td>
              <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Update
                    </button>
      </td>
      <td>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="disabled">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Remove
                    </button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>  Edit
                    </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to traverse to closest tr element, find inputs and buttons in it and set property `disabled` as `false` for them:

```
$(".btn-edit").on("click", function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input,button').prop('disabled', false);   
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: Thanks Mikind but btns are not enabling!

Comment: it is working now but ONLY on first click! I mean if you select the second edit button it is not working!

Comment: @Suffii: that is because you have not added the class `btn-edit` in next two edit buttons

Answer (score 5):

you need this:

```
$(".btn-edit").on("click", function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').find(':input').filter(':disabled').prop("disabled", false);   
});
```

You can use `.closest()` to traverse up to the `tr` then find all the `inputs` with `:input` and filter them not to select the `button` elements which are enabled by default.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.closest()` to traverse upwards to `tr` then use `.find()` to find all inputs using [`:input`](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

*Use*

```
$(".btn-edit").on("click", function() {
    $(this)
        .closest('tr') //Travese to parent tr
        .find(':input') //Find all input
        .prop("disabled", false); //set diabled false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".btn-edit").on("click", function(){
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input,button').prop('disabled', false);  
});
```